# Styling pseudo-elements when a link has wrapped?

Tags: css, pseudo-element, word-wrap

I've created an 'underline' animation that uses an ::after pseudo-element underneath the link. Here is the code for the link and the pseudo-element:

**Link**

```
a {
    position: relative;
}
```

**::after**

```
a:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    width: 0%;
    background-color: #ce3f4f;
    left: 0%;
    bottom: 0px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

This all works fine when the link is on a single line, but if the link flows onto the next line then it only fills across the bottom of the first line, as seen here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SX7o.jpg

If I inspect the element then it appears that the issue is not solvable, as the browser (in this case, Firefox) isn't selecting the entirety of the wrapped element:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/342GH.jpg

Is there a way of solving this purely with CSS, or is it a problem with the way the browser renders the objects? I have played around with a lot of `white-space`, `display` and `position` configurations but to no avail.

Here's an example of the behaviour:

https://jsfiddle.net/57Lmkyf4/

Comment: Can you perhaps provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: Sure, here is is: https://jsfiddle.net/57Lmkyf4/

Comment: I don't think pseudo elements can work in 2 lines. They are just rectangles. Most likely you'll need to apply `white-space:nowrap;` for your `a` to prevent this bug (and keep your links short).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done with CSS. (I've implemented it using JS for links that wrap over not more than 2 lines: https://jsfiddle.net/6zm8L9jq/1/ - you can resize the frame to see it at work)

In my Chrome (39.0.2171.95) the underline under a wrapping `a` doesn't work at all, while in FF it displays like in your screenshot above. Primarily this is because your `a` element is inline (default), and when it wraps, any pseudo/child elements that depend on its width get `0` width in Chrome and the element's width on the first row in FF. Inline elements don't have control on their own width/height properties (eg, you can't set a  `width:100px`  on them without changing them to block elements), and this also affects any absolutely positioned elements that depend on them for width/height.

If you call the `window.getComputedStyle` method on the pseudo element in FF and Chrome, like:

```
var a = document.querySelector('a');
a.onmouseover = function(){

    setTimeout(function(){
        var width = window.getComputedStyle(a,':after').getPropertyValue('width');
        console.log(width);

        },300); //timeout so that animation to 100% width is completed
}
```

...in chrome you will see `0px` while in FF you will see `100%` - and neither will span to actual 100% of the parent. If you added a child element (eg a `span`) to `a` instead of a pseudo element, you could investigate the child's actual width after `mouseover` by calling `getBoundingClientRect().width` on the child, in which case again, in chrome you would see `0px`, and in FF the width of the part of the parent element falling on the first line.

You can change the `a` element to `display: inline-block` and it will work, but it will obviously no longer wrap.

Comment: Hmm, that's really interesting - I was pretty confident that there wouldn't be a way around it, but I'm excited to delve a bit more into what you have said; it'd be fascinating to see exactly how and why the browsers do that.

Comment: Added a JS solution, you can check out the link in the answer if you want to wrap. Doesn't work for links wrapping on more than 2 lines though.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Sidd - I'll try it out when I get home.